# Real Time File Transfer using python script

Tags: python, file, rtp

I want to create an  application which needs from time to time do
file transfer (I want to write the server as well as the client).

What is the best way to do this file transfer?

Thanks in advance..

Nimmy...

Comment: FTP? It was invented for that.

Answer (score 0):

[Pyftpdlib](http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/) as a server.

and any linux box as a client.

Answer (score 0):

FTP Tunneled over SSH.
Use twisted and a good linux shell.